# Is it okay to use a "place" and "replace" button if an image has already been uploaded using the drag and drop or upload an image function?

Tags: user-behavior, buttons, drag-n-drop, uploading

I am trying to use this Drag and Drop / Upload image feature and put it inside a field. By adding or uploading a "logo", it will will be replaced by the image uploaded and buttons like Delete and Place icon will appear on the side. The question is, do i have to include a "replace" or "place" icon on the side? Or should it be inside the field which could be inconsistent where all action buttons should be a part of a group? Do a user expect that an image can be replaceable by clicking only the image?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If there is no logo at the beginning, you propose the user to Drag&Drop or to upload the image by "Choose file".

If there already is a logo, you don't do this, so a user can forget it is possible to do something with the picture. He/she might feel confused thinking it is not allowed to change, if he made a mistake.

The offer to delete or change should be clear and visible.

(However, I think the lower icon (to replace) does not suggest "replace". It's like "Properties" or "Edit text" (the red icon is clear). I would suggest using some kind of "Open file" icon, which is clearly "load a new logo". I would also propose to switch them, so "replace" would be the first thing a user thinks of, and "delete" the second.)

Perhaps it would be good to explain that the two icons are directly connected to the logo image. Maybe you should take all logo and icons in one bordered field, making clear it is the same meaning. You may leave them if the distance to other elements are enough to ensure user they are directly connected to the logo and nothing else.

For example, on Google+ there is a semi-transparent block over the logo with the text like "Change image".

Comment: Thank you so much :D How about about adding some notes that says "Note: Click the image to replace.", is it a good idea?

Comment: It depends, if your other icons are clear enough, I wouldn't place the text, but I'd expect some explanation when I move pointer over an icon

Comment: Fixed the icon :D